# getuserMedia() - doesn't work on localhost because it's unsecure origin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getusermedia, screen-capture

I am clearly on localhost.
I tried setting `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`.
I also made sure nothing is blocked under content and site settings.

There seem to be no more info on this online.

[image]

Comment: This is an `alert` modal, i.e your script produced it. Most probably, the error message is wrong on why the gUM request failed, and if I really had to make a blind shot, I'd guess either you already did block that feature previously and the browser is using the saved setting but you said you checked it, either you didn't interact with the page before the request is being made (e.g before you click anywhere). Could you post the code you use to make that gUM request?

Comment: Indeed I was too trusting to doubt the library, which simply checked location.host == ''localhost'

Answer (score 0):

When I have a problem with camera access inside of a Chromium based browser I go to `chrome://settings/content/camera` and check to see if `http://localhost:<port>` is blocked.

If you are serving locally localhost should work. However I had an Engineer accidentally click "deny/block" with the getUserMedia permission pop up. The above solved their issue.

In terms of your issue the alert is a logic popup checking for https before camera access, not an error with getUserMedia. You will need to check the code and allow localhost.  The following snippet allows localhost and checks for https if served.

Not all server configs do http to https redirect, therefore you should still protect the frontend code vs allowing it to fail at getUserMedia on a http:// link.

```js
if (location.hostname === "localhost" || location.hostname === "127.0.0.1" || location.protocol === "https:"){
    alert("Run WebRTC code");
} else {
    alert("Redirect user from http to https");
}
```